# Using selenium and Nunit testing How do I assert that a table contains specific text

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I have a selenium test that I am running on my project. I need to assert that some text exists in the first  element of the table.

```
public void TheUserHasAClaimTest()
{
    //Arrange

    //Act
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("SSN")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("SSN")).SendKeys("000000000");
    new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("stateId"))).SelectByText("Arizona");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnCheckForClaims")).Click();


    Assert.IsTrue(this.driver.FindElement(By.Id("Ssn")).Text.Contains("000000000"));
    driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("form.form-horizontal > input.btn.btn-primary")).Click();
    driver.Close();

    //Assert
}
```

Here is where I am trying to assert that text exists.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
         <th>Ssn</th>
         <th>State</th>
         <th>Claim Date</th>
        @foreach (ClaimViewModel claimHistory in Model.ClaimsHistory)
         {
             <tr>
                <td id="Ssn">@claimHistory.Ssn.ToString()</td>
                 <td>@claimHistory.StateName</td>
                 <td>@claimHistory.ClaimDate</td>
             </tr>
         }
     </table>
```

This is my CSHtml page. How do I assert that 000000000 is in the first  element?

Comment: What about this doesn't work? From a first glance this looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Returns that the element is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's invalid HTML, an ID is supposed to only appear once and you're using `id="Ssn"` in a loop.

Fix that and then review your test code. You may need to use `selenium.GetTable` to access the table data.